# Meyer's Implementation inheritance in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

Can someone give an example of [Meyers Implementation inheritance](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/oosc/inheritance-design/section_05.html#HDR19) in Java, the book in the link is about eiffel, but i need a java example.

I know java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so can we call it implementation inheritance if I implement an interface and extend a class?

Also does it have to have two parents to be a case of implementation inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions from the book go over this here:

> Definition: **implementation inheritance** Structural inheritance applies if
>   B obtains from A a set of features (other than constant
>   attributes and once functions) necessary to the implementation of the
>   abstraction associated with B. **Both A and B must be
>   effective.**

The classes A and B must not be deferred. That is the case when extending a non-abstract Java class A by a non-abstract class B.

> Definition: **reification inheritance** Reification inheritance applies if
>   A represents a general kind of data structures, and B represents
>   a partial or complete choice of implementation for that data structure.
>   A is deferred; B may still be deferred, leaving room for further
>   reification through its own heirs, or it may be effective.

The class A is deferred, so this would be the case when implementing a Java interface A or extending a Java interface A (the new interface would then be B)

The case you specify (implementing an interface and extending a non-abstract class in Java) is a combination of these two. The text makes it quite clear here:

> A common case is what will be called the "marriage of convenience", based on multiple inheritance, where one parent provides the specification (reification inheritance) and the other the implementation (implementation inheritance).

Comment: I think "The classes A and B must not be deferred. That is the case when extending a Java class A." might be misleading.

In Java a class B can extend a class A without A deferring any implementation: that is the case if class A does not declare any abstract method and if A itself does not inherit any abstract or interface methods for which it does not provide an implementation.

Comment: @Icarus I replaced "class" with "non-abstract class" in the answer. But I don't understand what do you find misleading, isn't what you describe the basic case of implementation inheritance above?

Comment: With "non-abstract class" I find it no longer unclear. Talking just about "class" as it was before was for me misleading as it would have included abstract classes.Thanks for the improvement.